# How to automate integration testing that requires multiple computers?

Tags: integration-testing

How do you automate integration testing that requires 2 or more PCs (distributed app)? What's your strategy for performing integration testing (or performance testing) on the cases where multiple machines are involved?

### Example

We need to integration-test our client/server app. To mimic the live-system, we need to deploy the client on one machine, and the server on another. Then we measure the TCP transfer speed.

Comment: What you are describing sounds like an integration test. A unit test typically involves testing a block of code. Proper terminology goes a long way in communicating requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to do this, but none of them are built into any frameworks that I am aware of.

Below are the three ways I have addressed it in the past:

1. use VMWare Server/ESX - What we have done most recently is to actually build VM images for the server and client machine with a mountable second drive (data drive). We then build and unit test our software, before the performance test we spin up the VM, then deploy the code to the data drive. After that we deploy a set of test scripts to the machines and kick them off (via Powershell). This works pretty well, has good replay-ability and allows us to give the test servers to other teams/customers for their evaluation. The downside is that it is very resource intensive.
2. Dedicated Server & Client Test Sets - We had two different Source Repositories, one for the server and one for the client. We then went through the build as above, but one at a time, deploying the server (and testing it against the old client), deploying the client (and testing it against the old server), and then deploying both and testing the combination. This worked fairly well, but required some manual testing for certain scenarios and could get cumbersome if we needed to test multiple server changes or client changes at the same time.
3. Test against production only - We only ever updated the client **OR** the server and then we updated that part and tested it against the current production setup. The downside of this of course is that we had to deploy much slower and make incremental changes in one system or the other, deploy, test and release, then make changes in the other component. Rinse and repeat.

If you have the resources I highly recommend #1. Its harder to setup initially but it pays for itself very quickly, and once its setup its repeatable for other products as well (as long as they follow a relatively similar deployment pattern).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your setup.  For example I needed to test a group of web services that my team created/modified.  During the test we deployed the app to one machine as the producer and used SoapUI to generated a few thousand transactions via many threads (from 1 to 100 threads as I remember).  That way we guaranteed the response and the SLA (service level agreement).